QEMU can only ping docker container
I have a docker container running QEMU that I need to give access to 2 interfaces. 1 a macvlan so that it can send/receive messages through a broadcast address as well as communicating with other devices on that network. 2 a bridge network for access to other networks.
As it stands:

the docker container and QEMU VM can ping each other
the docker container and other devices on the network can ping each other
the QEMU VM can access devices connected to the bridge network
the QEMU VM and other devices on the network are unable to ping each other

Dockerfile
it should be mentioned that the host machine is the gateway
FROM debian:trixie-20240926-slim

RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get --no-install-recommends -y install qemu-system-x86 \
qemu-utils \
samba \
iproute2 \
net-tools \
iputils-ping \
tcpdump

ENTRYPOINT ["tail"]
CMD ["-f","/dev/null"]

docker-compose.yml
services:
  windows:
    privileged: true
    image: myimage
    networks:
     bridge:
     private:
        ipv4_address: "192.168.5.206"
    container_name: windows
    devices:
      - /dev/vhost-net
    device_cgroup_rules:
      - 'c *:* rwm'      
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    ports:
      - 8006:8006
      - 3389:3389/tcp
      - 3389:3389/udp
    stop_grace_period: 2m
    volumes:
      - /var/win:/storage 
      -  /home/someone:/shared
networks:
  bridge:
   driver: bridge
  private:
    driver: macvlan
    driver_opts:
      parent: enp0s8
    attachable: true
    ipam:
     config:
        - subnet: "192.168.0.0/17"
          gateway: "192.168.5.201"  

I am configuring the network and QEMU VM by interactively running the following commands:
ip link add br0 type bridge
ip tuntap add dev tap0 mode tap
ip link set dev tap0 master br0 
ip link set dev eth1 master br0 
ip link set dev br0 up

ip address delete 192.168.5.206/17 dev eth1
ip address add 192.168.5.206/17 dev br0

qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -cpu host  -drive file=/storage/windows-c-drive.img,id=data3,format=raw,cache=none,aio=native,discard=on,detect-zeroes=on,media=disk,if=none -device virtio-scsi-pci,id=scsi -device scsi-hd,drive=data3  -m 4G -monitor stdio -boot d -drive file="shared/shared/Windows.iso",media=cdrom -drive file="shared/shared/virtio-win-0.1.217.iso",media=cdrom  -display vnc=:0,websocket=5700  -netdev tap,id=mynet1,ifname=tap0 -device e1000,netdev=mynet1 -netdev user,id=mynet0 -device e1000,netdev=mynet0

Which provides the following output:
W: /etc/qemu-ifup: no bridge for guest interface found
QEMU 9.1.0 monitor - type 'help' for more information
(qemu) 

Below is the VM ipconfig and ping result:

C:\Users\qemu>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Ethernet Instance 0 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::871f:325f:dfda:6dd0%5
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.5.207
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.128.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.5.201

Ethernet adapter Ethernet Instance 0 3:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Site-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fec0::7ed:baae:b34c:f6bc%1
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::a135:7c5b:16c:69bd%4
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.2.15
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::2%4
                                       10.0.2.2

C:\Users\qemu>ping 192.168.5.206 -S 192.168.5.207

Pinging 192.168.5.206 from 192.168.5.207 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.5.206: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.5.206: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.5.206: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.5.206: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.5.206:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

C:\Users\qemu>ping 192.168.2.1 -S 192.168.5.207

Pinging 192.168.2.1 from 192.168.5.207 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.5.207: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.5.207: Destination host unreachable.

Ping statistics for 192.168.2.1:
    Packets: Sent = 2, Received = 2, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Control-C
^C
C:\Users\qemu>\

What can I do to ensure that I can ping 192.168.2.1 or other devices on the network?
